# widgetVar not working properly in p:repeat for printing Charts

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to print a few chart objects generated inside a `<p:repeat></p:repeat>` tag.

I know that the regular `<p:printer>` tag does not work with primefaces charts due to the use of HTML5 Canvas...es? Canvii?

Either way, I grabbed [this JS function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213008/7591918) from another SO post, but I can't quite get it to work the way I want.

This is my panel with charts:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function exportChart(component) {
        //export image
        $('#output').empty().append(PF(component).exportAsImage());

        //show the dialog
        PF('dlg').show();
    }
</script>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" modal="false" header="Druckbares Diagramm als Bild" resizable="true">
    <p:outputPanel id="output" layout="block" style="width:1000px;height:300px"/>
    <p:commandButton onClick="javascript:PF('dlg').hide()" value = "Schließen"/>
</p:dialog>
<p:panel id="charts">
    <p:repeat value="#{AttributeChartsController.kacModel.chartWrappers}" var="wrapper" style="height: #{wrapper.drawHeight}" >
        <p:chart type="bar" model="#{wrapper.chart}" style="height: #{wrapper.drawHeight}" widgetVar="#{wrapper.widgetVarIdStr}"/>

        <p:commandLink id="lnk#{wrapper.widgetVarIdStr}" onclick="print(#{wrapper.widgetVarIdStr})">Print</p:commandLink>
    </p:repeat>
</p:panel>
```

I set my `widgetVar` to `widgetVarIdStr` which is generated for each chart like this, kind of:

```
//these are values retrieved from a database
long widgetVarId = 0;
for(Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry : keyAttribs.entrySet()) {
            this.chartWrappers.add(createChartWrapper(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
            widgetVarId++;
        }

private ChartWrapper createChartWrapper(String attribName, HashMap<String, String> keyValue) {
    //... create Chart, ChartSeries, enter values, etc
    wrapper.setWidgetVarId(widgetVarId);
    return wrapper;
}
```

The result is this, however:

[image]
The chart works, the print button is there and has the right value, but the widgetVar doesn't seem to get set properly within the `<p:repeat>` element. The `widgetVar` property is also nowhere to be found in the final generated source of the page, is that normal?

Here is my chartWrapper, there's probably a more elegant way to do what I want to do here but I'll stick with it:

```
public class ChartWrapper {
    private HorizontalBarChartModel chart;
    private long drawHeight;
    private long widgetVarId;

    public HorizontalBarChartModel getChart() {
        return chart;
    }
    public void setChart(HorizontalBarChartModel chart) {
        this.chart = chart;
    }
    public long getDrawHeight() {
        return this.drawHeight();
    }
    public void setDrawHeight(long drawHeight) {
        this.drawHeight = drawHeight;
    }
    public String getDrawHeightStr() {
        return drawHeight+"px";
    }
    public long getWidgetVarId() {
        return widgetVarId;
    }
    public void setWidgetVarId(long widgetVarId) {
        this.widgetVarId = widgetVarId;
    }
    public String getWidgetVarIdStr() {
        return "attrChart"+widgetVarId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you inspect the generated html? Are the widgetVars there?

Comment: As I said in my question,  the widgetVar property is also nowhere to be found in the final generated source of the page. So no, they are not for some reason. I also tried setting the id property for the `<p:chart>` tag, but that didn't work either. Edit: Here's what it looks like in the inspector on Firefox https://i.gyazo.com/6493d9afe41e411f47b104932172b9d2.png

Comment: Sorry, missed that part... Did not expect such fundamental information (kudos for checking this upfront) in the middle of a post. The widVar value is somewhere in the javascript e.g. the second 'chart' in `{PrimeFaces.cw('Chart','chart',` in the case of the ['export' example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/export.xhtml) it is not available as an html attribute. This can only be seen with 'view-source'

Comment: It's a little hard to read in the source since all the charts are in literally one line, but I get this (hope this is enough of a relevant bit) `<script id="j_id_x_3:0:j_id_x_4_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Chart','attrChart0',{id:'j_id_x_3:0:j_id_x_4',type...` - So I assume the widgetVar is properly set, then? I also edited my question and included the javascript I'm using, I will try with the one shown in the primefaces example.

Comment: Oh oh, okay, it still didn't work but I fixed it, my function call needed to be like this `onclick="exportChart('#{wrapper.widgetVarIdStr}')"`(note the single quotes to declare it as string) - however, I still get an error: `TypeError: PF(...) is undefined` This should be helpful in that regard -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319372/ - Thanks, it sure helped having someone else look over it with me xD

Comment: On what line?  And are you sure `out.appendChild(PF(component).exportAsImage()); ` is what you need?

Comment: I get the error with the JS from the example as well as the one I used. The call is from within a generated element in the repeat tag so there isn't a fixed line attached to it, however it happens in this call: `$('#output').empty().append(PF(component).exportAsImage());`as well as this one: `out.appendChild(PF(component).exportAsImage());` - And yes, the exportAsImage function is indeed what I need, I need to get the charts into a printable (literally, as in, on paper) format.

Comment: I did not mean you did not need the exportAsImage but if it should be done in that way...I mean, can you add an image to a div tag like that

Comment: The example said so, as well as the linked SO post. I'm honestly not sure how I could or should approach it in another way, it seems fine to me (if it worked)

Comment: PrimeFaces and the link use jquery and not plain dom like you do...

Comment: I should clarify, I've switched over to the example code since it's working for me now, and I was referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304803/primeface-print-doesnt-work-with-pchart/35213008#35213008 - it's the link from my post/question. I'm going to edit my question accordingly, it all works now however.

Comment: Please create an answer or even find a duplicate (I think there is, not for the charts specifically but for the missing quotes around the widgetVar. Adding 'answers' to questions is not what is common practice in StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

**I found the solution to my problems with the help of the comment section, it came down to some missing quotes in my jscript call**

`onclick="exportChart(#{wrapper.widgetVarIdStr})"` did not work because it was trying to pass an object to the function. I changed it accoridngly:

`onclick="exportChart('#{wrapper.widgetVarIdStr}')"` so now the actual widgetVar gets passed to the function as a string, which works as expected.